# How can I draw a map with lines using Here?

Tags: here-api

I have some csv files of latitude/ longitude points and I want to draw some maps using Here.

```
Points,Latitude,Longitude
Start_Point,37.8279,23.80773
Point_7,37.83347,23.80042
Point_6,37.83374,23.80056
```

I want to be able to see the directions from point A to point B on road.

I have uploaded the csv via "Your Geospace" but seems like I don't have access to GPX traces on support layers. Is this available only when you upload GPX files?

Is there a way not to only draw the points on map, but draw the whole route. I want something like a travelling salesman problem.

Comment: You can draw polylines with the HERE SDK, https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk-navigate/4.8.0.0/dev_guide/topics/map-items.html#add-map-polylines ... but from your question it is not clear which platform you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

We have HERE TCS examples page https://tcs.ext.here.com , https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3.1/ where you can find how to develop your applications - just mouse right click on an example and select 'View page source'

We have RME API (Route Match Extension) where you can upload your GPS coordinates in CSV format: https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3.1/rme_basic - this example makes a route match the points and calculate a route with showing on the map.

Travelling salesman problem you can resolve with HERE APIs:

1. HERE WSE API (Waypoints Sequence)
   https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/index.html
2. HERE Tour Planning API - https://developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/2.3.0/dev_guide/index.html